# How to remove callback from a Handler in Android Fragment

Tags: android, handler

I am having a `Fragment` in which I have used `Handler` which sends a request after each 60 seconds. This is working fine till I am on the same `Fragment`.

But when I redirect to other `Activity` or `Fragment` in some other `Activity`, the same `Handler` is working there also, I want this `Handler` to work only on that `Fragment` and want to remove it when I am on some other `Activity` or `Fragment`.

I have also used `handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);` on `onDetach` function of that fragment.

Please help me if you have any idea here, thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 4):

You should not call `removeCallbacks` at `onDetach`. Your `Fragment` can be invisible but still not destroyed (paused). notice that `onDetach` is called after `onDestroy`. According to the docs:

> Called when the fragment is no longer attached to its activity.  This
>        is called after {@link #onDestroy()}.

Use `removeCallbacks` on `onPause` instead.

If you want more info then please add your code and we will see why it's not working (but after changing the call to `removeCallbacks`)

Comment: Thank you so much... I have implemented this and now it's working fine.

Comment: Happy i could help. please don't forget to accept my answer and vote up if I've helped you